# Subsetting my sample and saving in a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a simple data set with 10 rows and two colums

What I want to do is sample 5 rows from my data 10 times without replacement and 
then store this new subsample with 10 different names.

This is what I have:

```
for (i in 1:10){

    print(Data[sample(nrow(Data), size = 5, replace= FALSE),] -> i)
    write.table(i, file = "data_i", row.names = F, col.names = F)
}
```

But in the new table I only get one subsample and with `" "` in each value of my data set.

Answer (score 0):

You reassign your looping variable `i` inside the loop. Plus, you got only one file name so that the file would be overwritten multiple times. Try this:

```
  for (i in 1:10){
    print(Data[sample(nrow(Data), size = 5, replace= FALSE),] -> x)
    write.table(x, file = paste0("data_", i), row.names = F, col.names = F)
  }
```